# Expanding in Context in a ListView - Android

Tags: android, android-listview, textview, android-context

I have a listView, one component of the row is a TextView. By default, I wish to show only 2 rows of text in the TextView. But if the user taps on the TextView I wanted to the textView to expand in context.

I actually have this portion working, but I want to have a more content indicator :

[image]

My current implementation (Below) has it's own issues w/ not collapsing if the list view is scrolled, but I will handle that by storing the values for each cursor record in some collection..

I tried using chatBubble.getLineCount() but that returns zero initially b/c it has not gone through onLayout (from my understanding).

I only wish to show it if there is more than 2 lines of content.

I figure my solution will be creating my own implementation of TextView which can handle some of my requirements, but not sure if anyone has any examples I can look at.. (Or other suggestions).

```
   <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_row_three"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linear_layout_row_two"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/munzeeQuickContact"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chat_bubble"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:background="@drawable/chat_bubble"
            android:text="I went looking for this particular token on a rainy day, and I was unable to locate it due to the bad weather, next time please leave an um I went looking for this particular munzee on a rainy day, and I was unable to locate it due to the bad weather, next time please leave an um" />
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/minimize_maximize"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/chat_bubble"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/chat_bubble"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_more"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is some of the source I currently have :

```
final TextView chatBubble = (TextView) view.getTag(R.id.chat_bubble);
        final ViewGroup expandableContainer = (ViewGroup) view.getTag(R.id.linear_layout_row_three);
        final ImageView minimizeMaximize = (ImageView) view.getTag(R.id.minimize_maximize);
        chatBubble.setOnClickListener(

                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    boolean isExpanded = false;
                    int lastHeight = 0;
                    // This is for the auto expanding text view
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (isExpanded) {
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.LayoutParams) expandableContainer
                                    .getLayoutParams();

                            params.height = lastHeight;
                            chatBubble.setMaxLines(2);

                            expandableContainer.setLayoutParams(params);
                            expandableContainer.invalidate();
                            minimizeMaximize.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        } else {
                            lastHeight = expandableContainer.getHeight();

                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.LayoutParams) expandableContainer
                                    .getLayoutParams();

                            params.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                            chatBubble.setMaxLines(99);

                            expandableContainer.setLayoutParams(params);
                            expandableContainer.invalidate();
                            minimizeMaximize.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }

                        isExpanded = !isExpanded;

                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I figure my solution will be creating my own implementation of
>   TextView which can handle some of my requirements, but not sure if
>   anyone has any examples I can look at..

Have a look at the class below:

```
public class LimitedTextView extends TextView {

    private boolean mStatus;

    public LimitedTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        Paint p = getPaint();
        String s = getText().toString();
        if (s != null && !s.equals("")) {
            int m = (int) p.measureText(s);
            if (m < getMeasuredWidth() * 2) {
                modifyParent(true);
            } else {
                modifyParent(false);
            }
        }
    }

    private void modifyParent(boolean how) {
        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) getParent();
        rl.findViewById(R.id.minimize_maximize).setVisibility(
                how ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        if (mStatus) {
            setMaxLines(40); // arbitrary number, set it as high as possible
        } else {
            setMaxLines(2);
        }
    }

    public void storeCurrentStatus(boolean status) {
        mStatus = status;
    }

}
```

The `LimitedTextView` will measure its text using its own `Paint` object and test it against the measured width. If it fits on the two allowed rows it will hide the `ImageView`, otherwise it will show it. It also stores the current status of row(expanded/not-expanded) and increases or decreases the maximum number of lines to obtain the proper appearance. 
In the `getView` method of the adapter you would:

- set the text
- set the status from a boolean array according to a position(this is also required to keep the rows in order as you scroll the list):

  `textView.storeCurrentStatus(mStatus[position])`
- set the `OnClickListener` on the `LimitedTextView` itself and from there update the status:

  ```
  mStatus[(Integer) v.getTag()] = !mStatus[(Integer) v.getTag()];
  notifyDataSetChanged();
  ```
- based on the same `mStatus` boolean array you'll probably change the drawable of the `ImageView`, to show a different one depending on if the `TextView` is expanded or not

I manually wrote it, so there could be some mistakes I'm missing right now, take it as an idea. The `LimitedTextView` could be improved as in performance, I also don't know how well it would behave if you want to animate expanding the text.