# xml for dropdown text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have used this forum when I didn't know how to do something, but now I have decided to begin participating in it.

I would like to know how could I do a dropdown text (maybe it has a specific name and that's why I don't find any results on the internet). I mean, I have some tags in the screen (About, Company, Contact, ...). Each of these tags has a down arrow on the right side, and when I click it, it has to display (and hide if it's clicked again).

Here are the links with the images of what I want to do.

http://i45.tinypic.com/4fzoso.png

http://i47.tinypic.com/2u5886q.png

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can use a listview existing out of textviews: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14073141/expanding-in-context-in-a-listview-android

Comment: that is definitely a ExpandableListView, but it's a slightly advanced topic for someone that is just beginning. If it's just a learning exercise I suggest trying a normal ListView and properly learning adapters and how they work before going to the Expandable type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did it with ImageViews and TextViews using the property android:visibility. Now that it's a static version is working properly. I hope that it continues working well when taking the information from the DB

Answer (score 0):

You should use an [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) component.
There is a tutorial for it [here](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/10/android-expandablelistview-example.html).